# How to find where a linux package has been installed

Tags: apt

I have just issued the `sudo apt-get install linux-source` command that installs the *linux-source* package, but I am not quite sure where this package has been downloaded to.

My question is how can I find where the package has been saved/downloaded to? It would be useful if I know the path to where it has been downloaded.

Comment: `apt-file list linux-source` should list all the files associated with the package.  Or `dpkg -L linux-source`

Comment: Package file (the .deb file) would be in /var/cache/apt/archives until `apt-get clean` is run.  Actual source files should end up in `/usr/src/linux` or `/usr/src/linux-version`

Comment: @ivanivan not quite, the kernel source is packaged as a tarball in `/usr/src`, *e.g.* `/usr/src/linux-source-4.9.tar.xz`.